# Admob refresh or new adrequest for new impression

Tags: admob, impressions

I just integrated Admob in my Android App.

I have confusion that, my app is kind of a live streaming app i.e. a user will be on the same activity for long time (in hours may be 1-2 hours).

And I have an adView
I don't want that for the time duration user is in the activity my ad counts as only one impression

I looked for it. So here is my question

1. I am making new adRequest manually every 15 secs using

   ```
   AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
   mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
   ```

   will it count as new impression
2. Is there any certain time period like 30sec or something that my ad should be visible to count as an impression.
3. I read this article about automatic refresh rate, does it mean my app will be automatically refreshed without new adRequest and will it be counted as new impression
   [Using automatic Refresh rate](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3245199?ctx=ui&hl=en)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Create single object of AdRequest(one AdRequest doesn't mean one Impression)
2. That is maintained and calculated by AdMob
3. Yes, If you select Automatic Refresh rate, otherwise your ad refresh at your custom refresh rate.

> Impressions, which is the count of each time an individual ad is
>   displayed in an app.

Comment: Okay thanks but if I make a new request manually a new ad is loaded, that must count as an impression?

Comment: banner Ad automatically changed/refresh so no need a new request but in Interstitial you need new AdRequest each time.

Comment: Thanks Man! Up voted, still looking for better explanation

Comment: If AdMob keeps giving the one same ad for a long period of time, then does it still count as one impression?

Comment: what do you mean by long period of time? Most of the time after one minute banner ad request for new ad if they get a response then that will count as one impression